# Add a new line of characters only after a line with specific characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to add a new line after every line that contains A1033 with a duplicate of that line except instead of A1033, I need it to say A3081.

So for example I need to go from this:

```
T9-P2818-L30:Count    
T9-P8629-A1033-L999:Count   
T9-P4960-V1000-P2818-L128:Foo
```

to this:

```
T9-P2818-L30:Count   
T9-P8629-A1033-L999:Count   
T9-P8629-A3081-L999:Count  
T9-P4960-V1000-P2818-L128:Foo
```

The searching part is straight forward `^(A1033)$`
but I'm not sure how to go about doing the rest using regex.

Comment: Match the whole line, and replace it with itself plus the new line … _“The searching part is staright forward ^(A1033)$”_ – that’s not going to find any of the example lines you have shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*:     `(.*)A1033(.*)` 
*Replace With*: `$0\r\n$1A3081$2`

Where:

- `(.*)A1033(.*)` - matches and captures into Group 1 (`$1`) any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last `A1033` on the line, then matches `A1033` and then captures the rest of the line into Group 2 (`$2`)
- `$0\r\n$1A3081$2` - inserts the whole match (`$0`), then appends a CRLF ending (use the one you need) and then appends Group 1 value, `A3081`, and then Group 2 value.

**[Here is the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SnTLjX/1)**.

See the screenshot:

[image]